# Logarithm laws with different base

Tags: logarithms

Hi I was doing question on logs And I came across a question that I am not sure how to do.

The question is

$$1+\log_2(5)$$

And the answer given is:
$$\log_2(10)$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+\log_2(5)=\log_2(2) + \log_2(5)=\log_2(2 \times5)=\log_2(10)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\log_2(2)=1$, and $\log_b(x)+\log_b(y)=\log_b(xy)$.